# Misalignment between Uniswap V2 calculateSwapInput and calculateSwapOutput functions

Tags: uniswap, math, uniswapv2

I've written my own functions `calculateSwapInput` and `calculateSwapOutput` for liquidity pools, based off of the Uniswap v2 spec. My functions are below:

```
// Calculates how much of one token we need to put into a liquidity pool, to get our desired amount out, given the size of the pools and a pool efe

function calculateSwapInput(
  amountOut: bigint,
  reserveIn: bigint,
  reserveOut: bigint,
  feeBps: bigint
) {
  const numerator = reserveIn * amountOut * 10000n;
  const denominator = (reserveOut - amountOut) * (10000n - feeBps);
  return numerator / denominator + 1n;
}
```

```
// Calculates how much we get out of a pool, if we input a specific amount
calculateSwapOutput(
  amountIn: bigint,
  reserveIn: bigint,
  reserveOut: bigint,
  feeBps: bigint
): bigint {
  const amountInWithFee = amountIn * (10000n - feeBps);
  const numerator = amountInWithFee * reserveOut;
  const denominator = reserveIn * 10000n + amountInWithFee;
  return numerator / denominator;
}
```

Say I want a certain amount out from my pool, call this "desired amount out". I need to know how much to put in to get "desired amount" out: I use `calculateSwapInput`.

But then if I pass that calculated input back into `calculateSwapOutput`, I get a different amount out than "desired amount".

Have I implemented my functions incorrectly? Or am I misunderstanding some aspect of this problem?